# How to stop a thread sleeping via an action/button click?

Tags: java

I am currently trying to build a simple program and have not covered action listeners as of yet, currently i am learning Swing/GUIs. I am attempting to display various images display every few seconds when a button is clicked, kind of like a slide show display.

The problem i have is how to actually stop the slide show? I have button that when clicked i would like to be able to stop the slide show but i am not able to click it when the display is running. I am not sure if the code below is correct, the thread interrupted is there just to ensure it the program doesn't stop/get stuck.

```
   startSlide.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
         {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent)
            {
              try{
                       Thread.sleep(5000);
                       Thread.interrupted();

                 } 
                catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ie){
                        System.out.println(ie);
                 }
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `Thread.sleep` within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This will cause the entire UI to stop and no new updates will be able to occur until it returns.

Instead, use a `javax.swing.Timer` which will allow to setup a callback after a specified period of time, which you can then take action within based on your needs.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details...

Comment: +1 for `Thread.sleep()` and `EDT`, I strongly recommend to get rid of it too.

Comment: OK thank you for your replies. I am reading up on implementing a Swing timer instead. As you stated the entire UI freezes and i did not know why.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.sleep()` method throws `InterruptedException` and responsible for interrupts. It means that when you have a reference for your thread somewhere outside, you may do

```
thread.interrupt();
```

And properly handle this interruption inside the thread itself, i.e. stop the slideshow or do whatever necessary.